# How can I add lat and lon dimensions to a non-standard netcdf file in python to perform analysis on IPCC AR6 sea level projection dataset?

Tags: python, geospatial, netcdf, ocean

I am working with IPCC AR6 sea level projection dataset which is a netcdf file. It is not like usual netcdf data whose dimensions are lat, lon and time. but its dimensions are quantiles, years and locations (there is a .lst file that contains the locations with the corresponding lat and lon). I need to have lat lon in the dimensions so that I can do analysis and computation. does anyone know how to fix it?
the header is:

```
xarray.Dataset

    Dimensions:
        locations: 66190 quantiles: 107 years: 14
    Coordinates:
        years
        (years)
        int32
        2020 2030 2040 ... 2130 2140 2150
        locations
        (locations)
        int32
        1 2 3 ... 1018003580 1018003590
        quantiles
        (quantiles)
        float64
        0.0 0.001 0.005 ... 0.995 0.999 1.0
    Data variables:
        lat
        (locations)
        float32
        ...

        units :
            Degrees North

        lon
        (locations)
        float32
        ...

        units :
            Degrees East

        sea_level_change
        (quantiles, years, locations)
        float32
        ...

        units :
            mm

    Indexes: (3)
    Attributes:

    description :
        Combined confidence output file for AR6 sea-level change projections
    history :
        Created Wed Jul 14 13:47:32 2021
    source :
        Files Combined: /projects/kopp/ar6/regional/pboxes/pb_1f/ssp119/total-workflow.nc,/projects/kopp/ar6/regional/pboxes/pb_1e/ssp119/total-workflow.nc
```

and the table:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   BREST   1   48.38   -4.49
1   SWINOUJSCIE     2   53.92   14.23
2   SHEERNESS   3   51.45   0.74
3   HOLYHEAD    5   53.31   -4.62
4   CUXHAVEN_2  7   53.87   8.72
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
66185   grid_-90.0_355.0    1018003550  -90.00  -5.00
66186   grid_-90.0_356.0    1018003560  -90.00  -4.00
66187   grid_-90.0_357.0    1018003570  -90.00  -3.00
66188   grid_-90.0_358.0    1018003580  -90.00  -2.00
66189   grid_-90.0_359.0    1018003590  -90.00  -1.00

66190 rows × 4 columns
```

anlysis IPCC sea level change datasets. the netcdf has lat lon as variables not as dimensions

Comment: Via online search, I found an Excel file under data in the Github [ipcc-ar6](https://github.com/podaac/ipcc-ar6) repo.